Can I save sticker pack from Client 1 to Client 2?
I have two clients connected to telegram.
I want to save my sticker pack.
stickers = await client1(messages.GetAllStickersRequest(0))
sticker = stickers.sets[0]

go_save = await client2(messages.InstallStickerSetRequest(
    stickerset=types.InputStickerSetID(
        id=sticker.id,
        access_hash=sticker.access_hash
    ),
    archived=False
))

But, I have error:

The provided sticker set is invalid (caused by InstallStickerSetRequest)

I understand this error, cause I have different access_hash for this pack from my Client 2. Do you have any idea how I could get the essence of the sticker pack in order to save it?
Of course, I have an idea to implement sending a sticker by message to two clients, then get the data of a specific sticker and get the information about the set and save it, but this is not a neat enough solution that I would like to avoid.
Save sticker pack from Client 1 to Client 2.

Yes, I can save.
Example:
stickers = await client1(messages.GetAllStickersRequest(0))
sticker = stickers.sets[0]

go_save = await client2(messages.InstallStickerSetRequest(
    stickerset=types.InputStickerSetShortName(
        sticker.short_name
    ),
    archived=False
))

